# Can someone cause me negative SEO by reporting to Google?

Tags: seo, google, negative-seo

I've been getting emails like this:

> Our site has been penalized by Google because of a handful of back
>   links pointing to our site (we have lost 80% of our traffic). I have
>   opened a line of communication with their WebSpam team and am working
>   to clear the penalty. HOW THIS AFFECTS YOU? We have isolated the back
>   links causing our penalty which we need to have removed, ONE is from
>   your site and I need to get that link taken down asap. Heres the
>   thing... In order to get out of the penalty they have asked me to
>   submit to them all the paid or unnatural links which are currently
>   pointing to our site and in the next 30 days I will be submitting to
>   them this list and unfortunately your site is included. HOW TO AVOID
>   NEGATIVE ACTION FROM GOOGLE If you can take the links down to hisdomain.com then of course I will be able to leave your site off that list. I really don't want to be the cause of a penalty to you, nor report anyone else's website to Google hence I'm reaching out to you now, and if you can get that link taken down ASAP then of course I won't include your site when I report back to them!

Do Google request such lists and can this cause a problem for my SEO? (of-course I have no idea who this is and have never sold a link to him or anyone else for that matter on my site, it's just User-Generated-Content)

Comment: Do they give you specifics about which links on which pages? If not it is generic for a reason. It's bulk spam/scam.

Comment: @JohnConde they actually give specifics. But even if they wouldn't, what can they gain by this anyway?

Comment: Depends on what the next step is. They might ask for access to your site to "help" you remove the links? or add code to do the same.

Comment: You might convey the info in John's answer to them, and that your site is composed of user-generated content. Threats to negatively impact your site's SEO is essentially extortion, so this doesn't sound like a legit request.

Answer (score 3):

Smells like bull doody to me.

- A handful of links will not cause your site to be penalized by Google.
- When you have the ability to disavow the links it makes it even more suspicious.
- Google doesn't ask anyone for lists of unnatural links. The aforementioned disavow tool handles that automatically.
- You've been getting *multiple* emails? Sounds like a persistent scammer to me.